# Какой смысл в этом комментарии?

Tags: обсуждение

Вопрос по [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721502/java-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8#comment1087188_721502) комментарию:

> и что? не находит?

Вот какой смысл в этом комментарии?

Если у участника плохое настроение и он видит неидеальный вопрос, то почему бы просто не пропустить этот вопрос, вместо оставления ненужных комментариев?

Comment: Просто пропускать нельзя, надо закрывать вопросы нарушающие правила.

Comment: а если у меня всегда плохое настроение, что же мне - все вопросы пропускать? Вопросу +1 за неравнодушное отношение.

Comment: @Igor, во время написания [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/708071/268112) ответа у вас точно было хорошее настроение

Comment: @neverforget, дописал комментарий к вашему вопросу. По сути проблема вопроса в том, что в нем нет вопроса. Есть поставленная задача, есть код, а вопроса нет.

Comment: @insolor, если что это не мой вопрос

Comment: @neverforget, ок. Но суть остается той же. В вопросе нет вопроса. Для того чтобы уточнить вопрос, нужны комментарии.

Comment: Добил своим пятым голосом цитируемый вопрос. Вопрос тот плохой, не соответствует правилам сообщества. Комментарий к нему был дан правильный, на мой взгляд. Пришли с вопросом - изложите суть, опишите ошибку и желаемое поведение кода.

Answer (score 6):

Не согласен с мнением в комментариях, что вопрос плохой. Его можно дополнить подробностями, после чего он станет вполне подходящим. Другими словами, вопрос
 *требует правки*, но он не плохой.

Указанный комментарий тоже не считаю плохим. Смысл его в том, что вопрос требует уточнения. Пара следующих комментариев хорошо раскрывают суть.

В любом сообщении про неработающий код должны быть три вещи:

1. Шаги воспроизведения (исходный код и подаваемые на вход данные )
2. Ожидаемый результат (что программа должна делать?)
3. Фактический результат (что происходит на самом деле).

Это не какой-нибудь наш местный каприз, что мы хотим этих трёх вещей. Нет. Это стандартные требования к багрепорту. Если вы устроитесь в какую-нибудь IT-компанию тестировщиком, то будете часто писать багрепорты из этих трех компонентов, а если разработчиком — то будете требовать от тестировщиков, чтобы писали. (Ещё есть четвёртый — рабочее окружение — но здесь оно необязательно).

В вашем вопросе не хватает:

- Входных данных: какую строку получает `Scanner(System.in)`.
- Примера ожидаемого результата: что программа должна вернуть в ответ на эту строку?
- Описания фактического результата: какая ошибка, на какой строке, полный стектрейс ([Что такое stack trace, и как с его помощью находить ошибки при разработке приложений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/510755/181472)).

Добавьте всё недостающее, и вопрос можно будет переоткрыть, а минусы — забрать.

---

К слову, в [аналогичном вопросе на Pascal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708064/181472) есть почти всё что нужно.